# Inserting elements before a list of indexes

Tags: python

Say we have a python list defined like

```
>>> letters = ['A', 'B', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'X']
```

How could you insert an element, say:

```
>>> c = 'T'
```

Such that letters list remains:

```
 >>> ['A', 'B', 'T', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'T', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'T', 'X']
```

That is, before each 'X' in the list is inserted 'T'.

My first try was to compute the 'X' indexes like:

```
>>> xpositions = [pos for pos, e in enumerate(letters) if e == 'X']
```

And then, execute the following loop:

```
>>> for xpos in xpositions:
>>>     letter.insert(xpos, c)
```

But then realized that after the first execution of the loop body, the xpositions are changed. How could be this achieved?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a 2nd array to form the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate from end to beginning:

```
for xpos in xpositions[::-1]:
    letters.insert(xpos, c)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to insert a list `['T', x]` every time `X` is found. Flatten the resulting mixed list of lists using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools
letters = ['A', 'B', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'X']
letters = list(itertools.chain(*[['T', x] if x == 'X' else x for x in letters]))
print(letters)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to build a helper function:

```
def inserter(iterable):
    for it in iterable:
        if it == 'X':
            yield 'T'
        yield it
```

Then either iterate over it or build a list from it...

```
result = list(inserter(letters))
```

Comment: Not a critique and I'm sure OP could do it themselves, but maybe best to generalize the `'`X'` and `'T'` away into parameters. Say, `target` and `letter_to_insert`.

Comment: @Christian yeah... will probably leave that to the OP... generalising further it could be made to accept a dictionary so it can be called as: `insert(letters, {'X': 'T', 'F': 'Z'})` or something

Comment: True, fair enough @JonClements

Answer (score 0):

```py
letters = ['A', 'B', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'X']
s = "X"
t = 'T'
i = 0
while i < len(letters):
    if letters[i] == s:
        letters.insert(i, t)
        i = i + 2
    else:
        i = i + 1
print(letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too much pythonic but works

```py
letters = ['A', 'B', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'X']


def add_charater_before_list_element(letters, character, element):
    result = []
    for letter in letters:
        if letter == element:
            result += [character, letter]
        else:
            result.append(letter)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(add_charater_before_list_element(letters, 'T', 'X'))
```

Result:

```
['A', 'B', 'T', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'T', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'T', 'X']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is after you append 'T' the X position will change.
So what you need to do is update the xpos by making a slight modification to your loop code

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'X']

xpositions = [pos for pos, e in enumerate(letters) if e == 'X']

# add the count + xpos to update the xpos after adding 'T' to your list
for count,xpos in enumerate(xpositions):
    letters.insert(xpos+count, 'T')

print(letters)
>>> ['A', 'B', 'T', 'X', 'C', 'D', 'T', 'X', 'E', 'F', 'T', 'X']
```